# Função de retorno do próximo caractere ASCII em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

> Faça uma função: `strShift()` que recebe uma cadeia de caracteres com
>   letras do alfabeto e retorna uma nova cadeia com as letras
>   substituídas por seus sucessores na tabela ASCII. Por exemplo, “Ana”
>   retorna “Bob” e “zaZA” retorna “{b[B”.
>
> A função deve retornar NULL se não houver memória disponível.

Eu fiz:

```
char* strShift(char *s) {
    int i;
    int tam = strlen(s);
    char* nova = (char*)malloc((tam + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (nova == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        nova = *(s + i + 1) ;
    }
    nova = '\0';
    return nova;
}
```

Não consigo entender mais o que fazer, onde estou errando?

A saída me dá um monte de pontos de exclamação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem vários problema no código. Eu não gosto da ideia de alocar memória só para isso, poderia alterar direto no objeto já existente. Mas se o exercício dede isso vamos fazer. Lembrando que se fosse mais que um exercício sem um `free()` vazaria memória.

Tirei as partes irrelevantes do código (provavelmente está aprendendo com material antigo.

O acesso ao conteúdo está confuso e mais complicado do que deveria ser, é só acessar como se fosse um *array*, assim evita problemas, acabou misturando endereço com o conteúdo e fez tudo uma coisa só, separando os conceitos de forma mais clara fica mais fácil acertar. Faça o simples primeiro, use a sintaxe fácil.

Em alguns pontos deveria acessar o elementos da *string* e não colocou índice algum para isso então automaticamente o índice é o 0, e aí quando colocou o terminador no lugar errado já melou o texto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strShift(char *s) {
    int tam = strlen(s);
    char *nova = malloc(tam + 1);
    if (nova == NULL) return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) nova[i] = s[i] + 1;
    nova[tam] = '\0';
    return nova;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s", strShift("anaz"));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/onzIvT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ShiftCharc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ShiftChar.c).

Comment: Amigo, perdão. Eu esqueci de mencionar algumas outras características que o exercício pedia. Como por exemplo o uso de aritmética de ponteiros, falha minha. Entretanto, já consegui aqui resolver com o que vc respondeu. Muito obrigado e grande abraço!